# Can I sell my half of a jointly owned mobile home to someone else?

Tags: united-states

My ex-girlfriend and I bought a mobile together, but I made all the payments and purchased the appliances and other necessities needed to be move-in ready. I now do not live in it with her. The mobile home is located in a mobile home park where My ex-girlfriend recently removed me from the lease. Can I sell my half of the mobile home to someone else?

Comment: Why would anybody want to buy half a mobile home, that they have no way to live in?

Comment: Now you know what prenuptial agreements are for, and will get one Next Time.

Comment: Since it's your mobile home, you can have it moved to another mobile home park.

Comment: @RonJohn Well, half of it.

Comment: What legal paperwork do you have?  If you have a written agreement that you own half (or you might have a title certificate, as with a car), then you could possibly get the GF to buy you out or something.  If it was just a verbal agreement... well, you know what they say about verbal agreements not being worth the paper they're written on :-(  So possibly a better question for the Legal site.

Comment: @ceejayoz If it's a double-wide, that'll work out perfect!

Comment: Do you need to be on the lease to live in your home ?

Comment: One is either _buying_ a home (typically with a mortgage associated with it) or _renting_ it (which involves a lease). So, if ex-GF has taken ex-BF's name off the _lease_, that is _not_ a _ownership_ deal but rather a _rental_ deal.

Comment: Its both. If I understand the OP owns (half of) the home but is resting the land which it is on. This is fairly common with mobile homes. They have been removed from the rental lease of the land but continues to own the home.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: In many, if not most (or even all) US states, mobile homes are generally treated as vehicles, rather than as real estate.  So there would be a title certificate issued by the state department of motor vehicles.  (At least in states I'm familiar with: the OP should look up the laws for his/her own state.)

Answer (score -1):

If you mean contractual joint ownership, then no, you must get consent from the other party. However, if you are the sole owner and had a non-contractually bound agreement to make payments or split the cost, then it is entirely your right to sell the home.

Hope you get everything resolved soon!